# Incorrect syntax near the 'ORDER'

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

This is my query, I want to fetch data by percent and random order, I get this 
error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

What is wrong here?

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM 
 (
 select * from (
 SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 7 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NEWID()) a
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 84 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 6 and IsSpecial=true and  Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) b
UNION 
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 72 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 5 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) c
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 60 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 4 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) d
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 48 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 3 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) e
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 36 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 2 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) f
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 24 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 1 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) g
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 12 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 0 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) h
)
ORDER BY Stars DESC, UpdateDate DESC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to give your table an alias.

```
string sql = @"SELECT * FROM 
 (
 select * from (
 SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 7 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NEWID()) a
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 84 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 6 and IsSpecial=true and  Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) b
UNION 
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 72 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 5 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) c
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 60 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 4 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) d
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 48 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 3 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) e
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 36 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 2 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) f
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 24 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 1 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) g
UNION
select * from ( 
SELECT TOP 12 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 0 and IsSpecial=true and Confirm='1' and show=true and ExpireDate  >=@ExpireDate ORDER BY  NewId()) h
) Results
ORDER BY Results.Stars DESC, Results.UpdateDate DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a table alias for the `SELECT` that you order. So just add a table name before the `ORDER BY` clause.